# Deepclone - object passed to ctor is no longer ==

Tags: .net, clone

See the !=
I need that to be an ==
Not just return true - be the same object

If I change MyObj1.MyRepeat the change is also in MyObj2.MyRepeat
If I change MyObj1Clone.MyRepeat it does not change  MyObj2Clone.MyRepeat (or MyObj1.MyRepeat)

Pretty sure I just need to write a CustomClone and not use this Serialize/Deserialize DeepClone
Just checking - is the there another way?

```
MyRepeatedObj MyRepeat = new MyRepeatedObj("xxx");

MyObj MyObj1 = new MyObj (1, MyRepeat );
MyObj MyObj2 = new MyObj (2, MyRepeat );

//  MyObj1.MyRepeat  == MyObj2.MyRepeat

MyObj MyObj1Clone = DeepClone(MyObj1);
MyObj MyObj2Clone = DeepClone(MyObj2);

//  MyObj1Clone.MyRepeat  != MyObj2Clone.MyRepeat


public static T DeepClone<T>(T obj)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        formatter.Serialize(ms, obj);
        ms.Position = 0;

        return (T)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
    }
}
```

As suggested by Hans I introduce a GUID as a PK and use that for override equals
.Equal returns true
== is still false as it appears DeepCone creates separate object

```
public Guid PK { get { return guid; } }
public override bool Equals(Object obj)
{
    // Check for null values and compare run-time types.
    if (obj == null) return false;
    if (!(obj is SearchEnum1MVand)) return false;
    SearchEnum1MVand comp = (SearchEnum1MVand)obj;
    return (comp.PK == this.PK);   // && comp.AndOr == this.AndOr
}
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return FieldDef.ID;
}
```

I apologize for not including more detail on the first post

```
public MyRepeatedObj(GabeLib.FieldDefEnum1 FieldDef, GabeLib.enumAndOr paramAndOr)
{
    // the si... are MyObj that I pass the reference with this
    siAll = new SearchItemEnum1(paramAndOr, enumSrchCond.All, FieldDef, this);
    siAllNot = new SearchItemEnum1(paramAndOr, enumSrchCond.Not_All, FieldDef, this);
    siAny = new SearchItemEnum1(paramAndOr, enumSrchCond.Any, FieldDef, this);
    siAnyNot = new SearchItemEnum1(paramAndOr, enumSrchCond.Not_Any, FieldDef, this);
```

When I serialize / deserialize that is 4 different this

But I serialize / deserialize the 4 MyObj - I will try serialize / deserialize MyRepeatedObj and then get the 4 MyObj as properties

DeepClone at the MyRepeatedObj fixed it

```
SearchEnum1MVand searchEnum1MVand = DeepClone<SearchEnum1MVand>(((SearchItemEnum1)fieldDefSSDrowSelected.SearchItems[0]).SearchEnum1MVand);
Debug.WriteLine(searchEnum1MVand.SIall.SearchEnum1MVand.MVid.ToString());
Debug.WriteLine(searchEnum1MVand.SIany.SearchEnum1MVand.MVid.ToString());
searchEnum1MVand.SIall.SearchEnum1MVand.MVid++;
Debug.WriteLine(searchEnum1MVand.SIall.SearchEnum1MVand.MVid.ToString());
Debug.WriteLine(searchEnum1MVand.SIany.SearchEnum1MVand.MVid.ToString());
Debug.WriteLine(searchEnum1MVand.SIall.EnterOrder.ToString());
Debug.WriteLine(searchEnum1MVand.SIany.EnterOrder.ToString());
Debug.WriteLine(searchEnum1MVand.SIany.SearchEnum1MVand.SIall.EnterOrder.ToString());
searchEnum1MVand.SIall.EnterOrder++;
Debug.WriteLine(searchEnum1MVand.SIall.EnterOrder.ToString());
Debug.WriteLine(searchEnum1MVand.SIany.EnterOrder.ToString());
Debug.WriteLine(searchEnum1MVand.SIany.SearchEnum1MVand.SIall.EnterOrder.ToString());
```

Comment: My crystal ball says that you forgot to override GetHashCode().  So you get the value returned by Object.GetHashCode().  Different values because they are different objects.

Comment: @HansPassant I put override GetHashCode() back in and they are still not equal.  I used to override GetHashCode() and Equals and it worked but I cannot override Equals any more as the object no longer has a PK.

Comment: Well, surely you are doing it wrong, but we can't see you doing it wrong.  A hash is almost never suitable for a primary key anyway, it is not guaranteed to be unique.  If you need a PK then just make it a property.  A Guid is always a good idea.

Comment: @HansPassant I am not doing it wrong.  MyObj1Clone.MyRepeat MyObj2Clone.MyRepeat now have the same hash and are still not equals.   I did not say I was using a hash as a PK - I said the object no longer has a natural PK.  GUID would probably fix this but it still leaves another problem not in the question.  I will test GUID for equals as that is the stated question.

Comment: `==` uses reference equality by default.  If you want to use `Equals` instead you need to override the `==` operator to call `Equals`.

Comment: @DStanley Fooling it to return true does not fix it.  A change to MyObj1Clone.MyRepeat does not show up in MyObj2Clone.MyRepeat.

Comment: What is your question? _"How can I create a copy of an object while maintainin reference equality?"_? Instead of flagging down comments please expand your questions using the proper terms. The built-in deserializers will always create a new instance, so you'll never get the same instance back. You'll have to create a custom deserializer that looks up existing instances and return those when you detect equaliry - again, _if_ that is your question.

Comment: @CodeCaster I have not flagged down a single comment. "Pretty sure I just need to write a CustomClone and not use DeepClone
Just checking - is the there another way?"  How is "I need that to be an ==" not proper terms?  That means I need the object to be the same - not just return true.  I felt like that was the best way to describe the symptom.

Comment: I meant that I think your comments sound a little bit rude to me to people who are trying to be helpful. :-) As for your question: it would really help if you can explain in words what you expect this code to do, what it actually does (intended or not) and what you suspect to be the source of this behavior. _"This makes == return false, I want it to return true"_ isn't really a proper problem description. Like I said, a `Deserialize()` won't just happen to return the same object instance as a (probably) previously deserialized object, why would it?

Comment: @CodeCaster OK thanks for your feedback.  Condescending was not my intent.  I get Deserialize() is not returning the same object instance.  That is why I said "just checking".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `==` is still false as it appears DeepCone creates separate object

Well, yes - if it returned the same object it wouldn't be a "clone"!

`Deserialization` always create new objects.  If you want a new parent objects but keep the references to child objects then you want a *shallow* clone.  There are a few options to do that:

- Add a `Clone()` method to `MyObj` that calls `this.MemberwiseClone();` (you can't call it externally because it's `protected` instead of `public`.
- Use reflection to loop through fields and properties. copying them to the new object

Comment: Please read the question again.  References to the same object are no longer references to the same object.  MyObj1.MyRepeat  == MyObj2.MyRepeat and MyObj1Clone.MyRepeat  != MyObj2Clone.MyRepeat.  Fooling it to return a true does not make it the same object and I need it to be the same object.  Writing a MyClone is not that big a deal.  I am just adding a ctor to all classes involved that take the class as input.

Comment: OK Yes I misread your question - what you want is a _shallow_ clone instead.

Comment: Sorry the question was not the clear.  I may be using terms wrong but I think I still need a deep copy.  I want a new MyObj1Clone  and MyObj2Clone and and new MyRepeatedObj that they both reference.

Comment: Yes you are using terms wrong - a deep copy makes a copy of child objects as well (recursively)  a copy of the outer object with the same internal objects is a shallow copy.

Comment: Sorry but I either don't understand or I am still using terms wrong.  I do want a fresh/new copy of all child objects as well.  But I need MyObj1Clone.MyRepeat == MyObj2Clone.MyRepeat to be the same (new) object and serialize / deserialize does not do that (and I get that).

Comment: "same" and "new" are contradictory.  You can't have a "new" object with the same reference.  If you want the same _values_ then a deep copy is what you want, but they will be different _references_ (and changing one object won't affect the other).

Comment: Same and new are not contradictory.  I need the two new objects to both have a reference the same new object.  MyObj1Clone.MyRepeat and MyObj2Clone.MyRepeat are both new objects - they just are the same object.  I know how to write a CustomClone to do this.  I was just checking if there was a way that Serialize/Deserialize would magically do this.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Sorry for the low quality post.  This is not a direct answer but if you had a proper question you could have answered.